# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access in Chrome with Facebook Plugins

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api

I am getting an error in Chrome when using a few Facebook plugins, including LIKE button and LIKE Box. This is the error I get:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://samplewebsite.com/ from frame with URL http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=18#channel=f3c….com&channel_path=%2Fchannel.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df105c9419%26. The frame requesting access set 'document.domain' to 'facebook.com', but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.
```

*I replaced the site domain for a different one

I tried different variations of the buttons, including XFBML, iframe, HTML5 but nothing seems to solves this. I also use a channel.html file.

My Javascript code initialization:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'some_app_id',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      channelUrl: '//samplewebsite.com/channel.html',
      xfbml: true
    });
  };
  (function (d) {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

The fb-root div exists on the page right above the script.

My doctype is for HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html
lang="en"
prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I also tried with the regular attributes without the prefix, but still get the same error.

Is there a solution for that. I can provide any information needed. Thanks!

Comment: [Google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unsafe+JavaScript+attempt+to+access+frame)

Comment: believe me, I spent hours trying to find a solution, read tons of articles, but nothing helpful that solves this :[

Comment: I believe you, just gave the link if you missed anything and because of `iframe` in your document can cause this kinds of errors and I think it's not harmful if it doesn't brake your page, [check my site](http://heera.it) and see the console.

Comment: you site don't have any errors?!

Comment: Did you check the console, and are not you talking about console errors ?

Comment: yep, I find it. So it seems that it isn't a problem. Thanks a lot for your time!